# How to upload PDF files from a fragment to firebase in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, startactivityforresult

I want to upload pdf file from the fragment inside an activity to firebase . there are lots of tutorials available for uploading the file from Activity but not for fragments.
Is it possible or not ? if yes then how can I do that so?
also the method which is used for this task was **StartActivityForResult** which has been deprecated, then how should I use the new method which is **registerForActivityResult** with Fragment.

Comment: Same code for activity or fragment. And for upload you dont need startActivityForResult.

Comment: If you're using Kotlin, most likely this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will help.

Comment: alright . I want to upload the pdf from phone's storage. isn't it need startActivityForResult? @blackapps

Comment: @AlexMamo I am using Java.

Comment: Nowadays you should use [registerForActivityResult()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/ActivityResultCaller#registerForActivityResult(androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContract%3CI,O%3E,androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback%3CO%3E)).

Comment: For which action do you think you need to use startActivityForResult (or  registerForActivityResult().) ? For uploading a file its not needed.